# QueryString, need always return array

Tags: reactjs, query-string

I use `query-string` in React project.

Used this code:

```
const queryString = require('query-string');

queryString.parse('foo=1,2,3', {arrayFormat: 'comma'});
//=> {foo: ['1', '2', '3']}.
```

When in search only one object, like this - `queryString.parse('foo=1', {arrayFormat: 'comma'});` this is return `//=> {foo: "1"}.`

Is exists way when this will do return only array? Something like that:

```
queryString.parse('foo=1', {arrayFormat: 'comma'}); this is return //=> {foo: ['1']}.
```

and if more then one

```
queryString.parse('foo=1,2,3', {arrayFormat: 'comma'}); this is return //=> {foo: ['1', '2', '3']}.
```